# All My Databases Are Gone?

Tags: mysql, innodb, permissions, phpmyadmin

Today I changed my username and password in MySQL and I logged into phpmyadmin to see that all my databases were gone.

I've tried changing the datapath but then I realized I didn't see any of my databases in the data folder either!

Can I get back my databases? Are they stored somewhere else?

[image: My Data Folder]

[image: All My databases gone...]

Comment: look into "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6"..as programdata usually have the files on by default...what was the old path...can u share variable value in my.ini

Comment: You saved my a** on this one, Thank you so much.

Comment: Hey @NawazSohail you should post your comment as an answer. I'd like to upvote it.

Comment: For backing up, you really should be exporting an SQL file rather than relying on backing up the files.

Answer (score 4):

Data is present in data folder of MySQL which is usually in ProgramData for windows installations. look into "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6"..as programdata usually have the files on by default

Comment: As promised, +1 for making your comment an answer !!!

Answer (score 2):

You're not seeing your databases in phpMyAdmin because you are logged in as the anonymous user. Log in using the new username and password you've created/changed to and you should see your old databases.

By default, phpMyAdmin uses the "[cookie](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_auth_type)" [authentication mode](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#authentication-modes), which means you're prompted when logging in. If you've changed that to be "config" you'll have to edit the corresponding user and password fields of `config.inc.php` to match the new information.

Answer (score -3):

All the data used to be in default location of pc in fact wherever we are located doesn't matter so the default location is Ubuntu 9.10

Moving the database from `/var/lib/mysql` to `/data/databases/mysql` you can go and check your data there. It will be stored there and sometimes data may be hidden we can unlock it for seeing as a guest. If we are admin then we can see easily and if we are some unknown user for the system then we have to get some privileges for seeing the data.

Comment: Have you seen that the question is about a Windows installation?